# Android deleting a contact using first and last name

Tags: android

I am trying to delete a contact by using the first and last name. I am also sure the issue is within my selection but I'm unsure what should be changed.

I receive an error. Fatal Exception: main  android.database.SQLiteException: no such column: data2 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, contact_id FROM view_raw_contacts WHERE data2 = ? AND data3 = ?

I am wondering where my problem is?

```
    private void deleteContact(String firstName, String lastName) {

        String selection = "";

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder op = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);

        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {firstName, lastName};
        selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME + " = ? ";
        op.withSelection(selection, selectionArgs);
        ops.add(op.build());

        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The code below which deletes a contact using a display name works. This is why it has lead me to believe the problem is with how I am using this: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME

I received the same error when I tried this: selection = String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME) + " = ? AND " + String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME) + " = ? ";

```
private void deleteContact(String displayName) {

    String selection = "";

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder op = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);

        String[] selectionArgs1 = new String[] {displayName};
        selection = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? ";
        op.withSelection(selection, selectionArgs1);
        ops.add(op.build());

    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue? You forgot to describe your problem **and** ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what worked for me. Not sure if there is a different way to do this.

```
private void deleteContact(String firstName, String lastName) {

    String selection = "";

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder op = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {firstName + " " + lastName};
    selection = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? ";
    op.withSelection(selection, selectionArgs);
    ops.add(op.build());

    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME is a string therefore it must be surrounded with quotationmarks try this:

> "'" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME + "'" + .....

Comment: He's using selection arguments to replace the question marks.

Comment: I am using withSelection. Which if you read how to use this. The question marks are replaced by the selection arguments firstName and lastName.

Comment: yes but only if you tell the selection that it should use the array to replace the values

Comment: I think you should look at the code again. I am doing what you are saying in this line of code: op.withSelection(selection, selectionArgs);

Comment: sorry... I'm a little bit tired... but how does your db look like... I think the column ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME does not exist or is not created or you don't have permission to access

Comment: I am trying to modify contacts within the built in android contacts list. GIVEN_NAME would be the contacts first name.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html

Comment: see my update... I think that is the problem... as I said I am very tired and didn't saw this at first ... of course you also need to apply it to the second argument ... if this don't works I am seriously to tired and I don't the the problem for now ;D